# get the position of the child div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get the position of the child div 'test1'.I want to get the left position from parent div.the distance between parent div and child div is '10px' I want t get 10 pixel.Now It prints 140px(calculates from the screen starting position) .

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.test1').click(function() {
    var p = $(this);
    var position = p.position();
    console.log(position);
  });
});
```

```css
.test1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="width:250px;background-color:red;padding:10px;margin:auto auto;height:100px" class="testParent">
    <div class="test1">one</div>
    <div class="test1">two</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to parent element, then `position()` will return position relative to the parent element.

> The `.position()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element *relative to the offset parent*.

***[Source](https://api.jquery.com/position/)***

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.test1').click(function() {
    var p = $(this);
    var position = p.position();
    console.log(position);
  });
});
```

```css
.test1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="position:relative;width:250px;background-color:red;padding:10px;margin:auto auto;height:100px" class="testParent">
    <div class="test1">one</div>
    <div class="test1">two</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
    <div class="test1">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```